# How to extract value from re?

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re

cc = 'test 5555555555555555/03/22/284 test'

cc = re.findall('[0-9]{15,16}\/[0-9]{2,4}\/[0-9]{2,4}\/[0-9]{3,4}', cc)

print(cc)
```

> [5555555555555555/03/22/284]

This code is working fine but if i put `5555555555555555|03|22|284` on **cc variable** then this output will come:
`[]`

I want one condition if it contains '|' then it gives output: `5555555555555555|03|22|284` or '/' then also it will give output: `5555555555555555/03/22/284`

Comment: You told `re.findall` that you are looking for `/`, therefore it will not find `|`.

Comment: Yes I know that, edit re.findall add a condition that if it contains ```\``` then it will extract ```\``` and if it contains ```|``` then it will extract ```|```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace all the `/`s in your regex (which incidentally don't need to be backslashed) with `[/|]`, which matches either a `/` or a `|`. Or if you want backslashes, too, as in your comment on [Zain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2355176/zain-ul-abidin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123789/797049), `[/|\\]`. (You should always use raw strings `r'...'` for regexes since they have their own interpretation of backslashes; in a regular string, `[/|\\]` would have to be written `[/|\\\\]`.)

```
match = re.findall(
        r'[0-9]{15,16}[/|\\][0-9]{2,4}[/|\\][0-9]{2,4}[/|\\][0-9]{3,4}',
        cc)
```

Any other characters you want to include, like colons, can likewise be added between the square brackets.

If you want to accept repeated characters – and treat them as a single delimiter –  you can add `+` to accept "1 or more" of any of the characters:

```
match = re.findall(
        r'[0-9]{15,16}[:/|\\]+[0-9]{2,4}[:/|\\]+[0-9]{2,4}[:/|\\]+[0-9]{3,4}',
        cc)
```

But that will accept, for example, `555555555555555:/|\\03::|::22\\//284` as valid. If you want to be pickier you can replace the character class with a set of alternates, which can be any length. Just separate the options via `|` – note that outside of the square brackets, a literal `|` needs a backslash – and put `(?:`...`)` around the whole thing: `(?:/|\\|\||:|...)` whatever, in place of the square-bracketed expressions up there.

I don't recommend assigning the result of the `findall` back to the original `cc` variable; for one thing, it's a list, not a string. (You can get the string with e.g. `new_cc = match[0]`).

Better to create a new variable so (1) you still have the original value in case you need it and (2) when you use the new value in later code, it's clear that it's different.

In fact, if you're going to the trouble of matching this pattern, you might as well go ahead and extract all the components of it at the same time. Just put `(`...`)` around the bits you want to keep, and they'll be put in a tuple as the result of that match:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'([0-9]{15,16})[:/|\\]+([0-9]{2,4})[:/|\\]+([0-9]{2,4})[:/|\\]+([0-9]{3,4})')
cc = 'test 5555555555555555/03/22/284 test'
match, = pat.findall(cc)
print(match)
```

Which outputs this:

```
('5555555555555555', '03', '22', '284')
```

Comment: No it not worked, if i put ```cc = 'test 5555555555555555\03\22\284 test'```

Comment: If you literally put `'test 5555555555555555\03\22\284 test'`, then what you got is a bunch of fives followed by control-C (code point 3), control-R (code point 18, octal 22), control-B (code point 2), and then "84". If you want a string with literal backslashes in it, you have to either double them or use `r'`...`'` quotes.

Comment: Ok then give me a code suitable for that also.

Comment: and I have one more doubt, if ```cc = 'test 5555555555555555::02:25:284'``` i want for this also, if i will add ```::``` in regex then it will think they both are separate.

Comment: You want something that works for the control-character case? That makes no sense. That's an error in how you entered the string as a _literal in the Python code_. There aren't any backslashes in the string at all.

Comment: Ok so any way to fix backslash error? And to extract ```::``` also.

Comment: When you assign `cc` in your test code, use `r'`...`'` or double the backslashes, e.g. `cc = r'test 5555555555555555\03\22\284 test'` or `cc = 'test 5555555555555555\\03\\22\\284 test'`.  See my edited answer for the multiple-colon thing.

Comment: Oh thanks it worked, my last question, if it contains anything like /,\, , ::, :, then it should give | in return for example my ```cc = r'test 5555555555555555\03\22\284 test'``` ```cc = re.findall(
        r'[0-9]{15,16}[:/|\\]+[0-9]{2,4}[:/|\\]+[0-9]{2,4}[:/|\\]+[0-9]{3,4}',
        cc)``` then it gives output: ```5555555555555555\\03\\22\\284``` but atlast i want in result ```[5555555555555555|03|22|284]``` in return for all conditions, is it possible?

Comment: Why not just have it capture the components so that they're returned in a tuple by `findall`, instead of making another string you have to turn around and split? You can always `join` the tuple back together if you need the string in what I suppose is its canonical form. (See edit.)

Comment: I seen, but it separates it by ```,``` i want to separate that by ```|```

Comment: The comma is part of Python syntax. It's not a string with commas in it, it's a list

Comment: Ok so u can add | in that? Like: ```[5555555555555555|03|22|284]``` is it possible?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what's going on here.  What you're starting with is a string, a single value, made up of text. 

When Python prints out something like `[5555555555555555,03,22,284]`, that's not a string. There is nowhere in the memory of Python where you could look and find those commas in order to change them to pipes. Or the square brackets, for that matter. That's just the _printable representation_ of a list, which is (in this case) four separate numbers. If you want to print them out joined by pipes, then just do `print('|'.join(list goes here))`.

Comment: Okay I understood but is it possible to print like what I said? Or should I replace```,``` with ```|``` ? I don't want comma and bracket (, i want like this ```[5555555555555555|03|22|284]```

Comment: `print('[' + '|'.join(match) + ']')`

Comment: Btw anyway is there to extract cc from CCNUM   4742899001757624
EXP   25/06
NAME   천홍렬
CVV   518 the output should be: ```4742899001757624|06|25|518```

Answer (score 0):

Define both options in re to let your string work with both e.g. the following RE used checks for both "\" and also "|" in the string

```
import re

cc = 'test 5555555555555555/03/22/284 test'
#cc = 'test 5555555555555555|03|22|284 test'

cc = re.findall('[0-9]{15,16}[\/|][0-9]{2,4}[\/|][0-9]{2,4}[\/|][0-9]{3,4}', cc)


print(cc)
```

Comment: If it works for you then mark it accepted so that others will also get beneficial help from this answer

Comment: Ok, but output ```[]``` is comming when I have added ```cc = 'test 5555555555555555\03\22\284 test'```,  I want if it contains ```\``` then it will also work.

Comment: keep adding all optional characters in the re where i added | to let your re work with as many separaters you want,

Comment: I have added but it gives output ```[]``` in ```cc = 'test 5555555555555555\03\22\284 test'``` i have also added optional character ```\```

Comment: Wive me a reply man.

Comment: the "\" is a special character in re so you have to escape it use "\\" to use it for detection

Comment: It not works bro u can check